# github remove single file from commit history

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I would like to remove a single file from my commit histories. I have already deleted the file, not knowing that it is still visible in my commit histories (I'm new to github...). There are several posts about how to remove the entire commit history as well as how to amend a commit that hasnt been pushed, but I have already pushed several times.

Is there a way to force delete all traces a single file?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, github even got doc about it: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/